# Threejs Clipping Objects Contained Within A Mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can a clipping plane be setup so that all child objects on baseObject are clipped when outside the baseObject?

In this example the childObject should only show the region inside the parent and not show anything outside the parent's bounds.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bryaan/VsWb9/9026/)

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var baseObject = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20, 20 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
var childObject = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

// Set the child object to straddle the baseObject's border.
childObject.position.set(50, 0, 0)

baseObject.add(childObject)
```

Comment: I think this question would benefit from some screen shots, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @pailhead I added a jsfiddle example

Comment: @BAR your fiddle is using a revision of three.js that is 5 years old. Always use the most recent revision. Updated and corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pph4m3gm/. Study the three.js examples.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks a lot West!

Comment: @WestLangley What is the 'center' origin that the planes' signed distance constant refers to? Is it that of the parent object? So in my case the baseObject?  Or is it relative to the global scene origin?